# Does Lua load the whole file in memory while reading line by line?

Tags: lua, torch

I am using the following code to load a very large file (around 16GB) in Lua and getting out of memory issues. I am wondering if the following code, loads the whole file in memory and then iterates line by line or just one line is loaded at a time?

```
for line in f:lines() do ... end
```

Are there any better ways of loading large files in Lua?

Comment: What you have looks fine.  Maybe if you show us the complete code we can help, because the bug is not in what you've shown.  You also haven't shown us the complete error message.

Comment: No. In such case Lua does not store whole file. But may be your rest code prevent gc to free memory.

Comment: Iterator `file:lines()` does not load the whole file at once.

Comment: Thanks Guys... i definitely have a lot going into my code, and i was suspecting that reading the file might be the reason for out of memory. I will dig deeper and get back.

Answer (score 0):

No and yes.

Your construct indeed reads lines one by one and it they are going out of scope immediately after `end` of `for` block. However, Lua does not actually free any system memory at that time, but either does it periodically in small garbage collection steps or in one big sweep on demand. Lua won't bother agressively cleaning up it's internal storage when it does have memory.

You'll need to either set up GC configuration/memory limits approriately to make Lua more aggressive or manually call `collectgarbage` once per some reasonable amount of lines.

Comment: Every out-of-memory event will cause collecting the garbage.  If Lua crashed with OOM error, that means there are no garbage to be collected, the whole memory is filled with data referenced by user.